# Knockout value binding for select list works intermittently

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a select list which is bound to an options object being called via a web API. The object is given below.

```
[
{
    "ID": 1,
    "Status": "Unallocated"
},
{
    "ID": 2,
    "Status": "Allocated"
},
{
    "ID": 3,
    "Status": "Checked out"
},
{
    "ID": 4,
    "Status": "QA1"
},
{
    "ID": 5,
    "Status": "QA2"
},
{
    "ID": 6,
    "Status": "QA3"
},
{
    "ID": 7,
    "Status": "QA4"
},
{
    "ID": 8,
    "Status": "QA5"
},
{
    "ID": 9,
    "Status": "Invalidated"
},
{
    "ID": 10,
    "Status": "Delivered"
},
{
    "ID": 11,
    "Status": "Ready for Review"
},
{
    "ID": 12,
    "Status": "Reviewed"
},
{
    "ID": 13,
    "Status": "Ready To Print"
},
{
    "ID": 14,
    "Status": "Edited"
},
{
    "ID": 15,
    "Status": "Archived"
}
]
```

The select list is defined as

```
<select id="statusName" name="statusName" data-bind="options:Status,optionsText:'ID',optionsValue:'ID','optionsCaption':'All Status...',value:selectedStatus"></select>
```

The status that needs to be selected is coming via a query string. I grab the query string value, populate the selectedStatus observable and then bind the view model in my document.ready, something like this

```
 var deliveredTransVM = function () {

  var selectedStatus = ko.observable();

 //Get Status

 //Other functions

 return{

    selectedStatus:selectedStatus

     }

}();



$(function(){

 // get the id from the url
 var tId= getFromUrl('status');

 if (tId!=null && tId!='' && tId!='undefined')
 {
    deliveredTransVM.selectedStatus(tId); 
 }
   ko.applyBindings(deliveredTransVM);

 });
```

I cannot create a fiddle since I cannot put a query string in there. T

The problem is that the select gets values set intermittently. Sometimes it works and at other times selectedStatus is undefined as shown in the image below. I have logged the observable  prior to binding and it is always populated. I have tried setting it after ko.applyBindings but get the same issue.

I have played with removing the optionsValue in the select but that doesnt help. The ko.applyBidnings is being fired after the ajax promise is resolved.Any explanations would be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, the code works... I suspect something else in your code is coming back through and stepping on your value.

BTW, you can fiddle this... just mock your function.

```
var statuses = [{"ID":1,"Status":"Unallocated"},{"ID":2,"Status":"Allocated"},{"ID":3,"Status":"Checked out"},{"ID":4,"Status":"QA1"},{"ID":5,"Status":"QA2"},{"ID":6,"Status":"QA3"},{"ID":7,"Status":"QA4"},{"ID":8,"Status":"QA5"},{"ID":9,"Status":"Invalidated"},{"ID":10,"Status":"Delivered"},{"ID":11,"Status":"Ready for Review"},{"ID":12,"Status":"Reviewed"},{"ID":13,"Status":"Ready To Print"},{"ID":14,"Status":"Edited"},{"ID":15,"Status":"Archived"}];

var deliveredTransVM = function () {
  var Status = ko.observableArray(statuses);
  var selectedStatus = ko.observable();

  return{

    selectedStatus:selectedStatus,
      Status:Status

     }

}();

function getFromUrl(x) {
    return 11;
}


$(function(){

 // get the id from the url
 var tId= getFromUrl('status');

 if (tId!=null && tId!='' && tId!='undefined')
 {
     console.log(tId);
    deliveredTransVM.selectedStatus(tId); 
 }
   ko.applyBindings(deliveredTransVM);

 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brettwgreen/ov1nqxux/

Comment: Hard coding the value in the observable always works..even in my live code. The observable is not being used anywhere else in the js file. I have tried renaming the variable to test for naming clashes.. but it still fails intermittently.

Comment: Then it sounds like a timing thing... the getFromUrl function is most likely an AJAX call which is async. Instead of pulling that right into a variable, make the call and in the success function, set the observable. You can setup a boolean observable if you want to disabled the dropdown until the call finishes.

Comment: I had the apply bindings in a $.when call.. However after wasting a whole day, I realised that I had not placed a return before my $.ajax call so the promise was not being returned.. Ah well.. Live and learn